# Problems with rspec 3, capybara and machinist 2

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails, machinist

I have this feature test (Store model have a uniqueness validation):

```
feature "Index" do
  before do
    3.times { Store.make! }
  end
  scenario "User visit index" do
    visit stores_path
     within("table.table") do
       Store.all.each do |store|
         expect(page).to have_content(store.name)
       end
     end
   end
end
```

When i run the test, randomly fails:

```
Failure/Error: 3.times { Store.make! }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: name has already been taken
```

My blueprint is (follow the machinist documentation to generate a unique record):

```
Store.blueprint do
  name { "store #{sn}" }
end
```

I use DatabaseCleaner gem, then my config rails_spec:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'pundit/rspec'
require 'database_cleaner'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false


  config.before(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = if example.metadata[:js]
      :truncation
    else
      :transaction
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  DatabaseCleaner.logger = Rails.logger

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
```

That errors are driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the following in your `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.before :suite do |example|
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = example.metadata[:js] ? :truncation : :transaction
end

config.before do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```